# Send ffmpeg segmented files to Remote location

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I would like to segment a video file using ffmpeg and send the segmented files to a remote http url instead local server disk

I can run this command, which will store files in a directory

**ffmpeg -i  [input url]  -map 0 -codec:v libx264 -codec:a mp2 -f segment -flags -global_header -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10** ***segment%03d.ts***

What I would like to do is

**ffmpeg -i  [input url]  -map 0 -codec:v libx264 -codec:a mp2 -f segment -flags -global_header -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10** ***`http://url/ts_file`***

It gives error as Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Error number -22 occurred

Is it possible to do in ffmpeg?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you expect this feature to work? HTTP PUT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solution, the trick is append the *segment%03d.ts* at end of url

```
val output_url =  "http://"+request.host+"/ts_file/"

ffmpeg -i [input url] -map 0 -codec:v libx264 -codec:a mp2 -f segment -flags -global_header -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 "+output_url+"segment%03d.ts
```

in my route file (I am using Play with Scala)

```
POST   /ts_file/:file_name                       controllers.Application.ts_file(file_name: String)
```